# Show tuple in a table Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I have this code:

```
import pymysql
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button

db = pymysql.connect("host", "user", "password", "database")
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT phone_info FROM ants WHERE id='onexT1'")
data_list = cursor.fetchall()
hello = list(data_list)

class ViewButton(Button):

    def print_data(self, data):
        print(data)

KV = '''

<ViewButton>:
    on_release:
        root.print_data(self.data)

RecycleView:
    data: ()
    viewclass: 'ViewButton'
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        orientation: 'vertical'

'''


class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        root = Builder.load_string(KV)
        root.data = (item for item in hello)
        return root

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test().run()
```

Basically, the result from the query in the database is stored as a tuple. However when I run it, it returns an error:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'
```

So I tried converting the tuple to a list but it returns the same error as above.

What I want is to display the contents of the tuple/list in a table using recycleview. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RecycleView needs an iterable of a hashtable, for example a list of dictionaries, where the keys of the dictionaries are the properties that will be used in the viewclass, this is indicated in the [docs](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.recycleview.html#kivy.uix.recycleview.RecycleView.data):

> **data:**
>
> The data used by the current view adapter. This is a list of dicts
>   whose keys map to the corresponding property names of the viewclass.
>
> data is an AliasProperty that gets and sets the data used to generate
>   the views.

[fetchall](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/cursors.html#pymysql.cursors.Cursor.fetchall) returns a list of tuples, and we must convert that list of tuples to a list of dictionaries, where the dictionary key is "text" since it is the property that is used by ViewButton.

On the other hand ViewButton does not have the data property but text, so you must save that information.

```
...
data_list = cursor.fetchall()

hello = [({"text": result[0]}) for result in data_list] # convert

class ViewButton(Button):
    def print_data(self, data):
        print(data)

KV = '''
<ViewButton>:
    on_release:
        root.print_data(self.text) # <--- 

RecycleView:
    viewclass: 'ViewButton'
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        orientation: 'vertical'
'''

class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        root = Builder.load_string(KV)
        root.data = hello
        return root

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test().run()
```

Comment: Can I ask a question? From the track.py script here: https://github.com/Jezrianne/ANTS/blob/master/track.py It just returns a button when I toggle the track tab which is supposed to show the table as you answered. Any help on that matter? Thanks :)

Comment: @JezreelMartin Why Track inherits from Screen and Button ?, both are widgets and it is not correct to inherit from both.

Comment: Oh ok thanks so should I just leave it to inherit only from screen? or is it because it inherits from button that it only returns a button? Thanks :)

Comment: @JezreelMartin You still do not answer my question, what is your goal with that inheritance?

Comment: Well because that screen returns buttons?

Comment: @JezreelMartin What do you mean by returning buttons? If you want that screen to have a button, you must use a layout, for example BoxLayout.

Comment: I mean it just returns the buttons as you answered.

Comment: I just thought should I remove the screen inheritance and just inherit from button?

Comment: @JezreelMartin In my solution that part I copy it from your code, I just change self.data to self.text. I do not understand what you want.

Comment: It is as the question says: i want to show tuples in a table and your answer is exactly what I needed however, when I tried to plug it in the project in github, it does not return the output as you answered

Comment: @JezreelMartin Your code does not make sense, you are combining things, do you want your screen to have a button or not?

Comment: I want it to have a button :)

Comment: Sorry if I am combining things I'm still getting the feel of the kivy framework:)

Comment: @JezreelMartin I recommend you to do a mockup of your application, describe the functions clearly, etc before trying to do something. Another recommendation if you do not know about a topic is better to try the examples and understand them, for example with the RecyclerView review the docs and examples. Trying to do a project without understanding how basic classes work is like wanting to run without knowing how to walk. bye